# Linq Include Extra Column in GroupBy Selection

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a "ReactionSimple" column that I'd like to include in the GroupBy selection but when I include it in the Group By it throws off the returned row count in a big way. Is there a way to include the commented out column in the final grouped selection without throwing off the result count. I'm a LINQ noob.

```
        var reactivityResults = new List<ReactivityResultViewModel>();
        var reactivityResults2 = new List<ReactivityResultViewModel>();
        var classifications = GetMaterialClassifications(test.TestType);
        var antigens = _db.Antigens.ToList();
        if (test.ResultSets.Any())
        {
            var testResult = test.ResultSets.FirstOrDefault();
            var dateReported = testResult.DateReported;
            var details = testResult.ResultSetDetails.ToList();
            if (details.Any())
            {
                reactivityResults = (from d in details
                                     join a in _db.Antigens on d.AntigenId equals a.AntigenId
                                     join ma in _db.MaterialAntigens on a.AntigenId equals ma.AntigenId
                                     join md in _db.MaterialDefs on ma.MaterialDefId equals md.MaterialDefId
                                     join c in classifications on md.MaterialId equals c.MaterialId
                                     select new ReactivityResultViewModel
                                     {
                                         MaterialId = c.MaterialId,
                                         MaterialName = c.MaterialName,
                                         IsActive = md.IsActive,
                                         ReactionSimple = (ReactionTypeEnum)d.ReactionSimple,
                                         TestId = test.TestId,
                                         AccessionId = test.AccessionId,
                                         PatientFirstName = test.Patient.Party.NameFirst,
                                         PatientLastName = test.Patient.Party.NameLast,
                                         TestType = (TestTypeNoFlagsEnum)test.TestType,
                                         DateReported = dateReported,
                                         ManufacturerId = c.ManufacturerId,
                                         ManufacturerName = c.ManufacturerName
                                     })
                                     .OrderBy(x => x.MaterialName)
                                     .ToList();

                var sreactivityResults2 = reactivityResults
                    .GroupBy(x => new {
                        x.MaterialId, x.AccessionId, x.DateReported,
                        x.IsActive, x.ManufacturerId, x.ManufacturerName,
                        x.MaterialName, x.PatientFirstName, x.PatientLastName,
                        x.TestId, x.TestType,
                        //x.ReactionSimple
                    })
                    .Select(x => new ReactivityResultViewModel
                    {
                        MaterialId = x.Key.MaterialId,
                        MaterialName = x.Key.MaterialName,
                        IsActive = x.Key.IsActive,
                        //ReactionSimple = x.Key.ReactionSimple,
                        TestId = test.TestId,
                        AccessionId = test.AccessionId,
                        PatientFirstName = test.Patient.Party.NameFirst,
                        PatientLastName = test.Patient.Party.NameLast,
                        TestType = (TestTypeNoFlagsEnum)test.TestType,
                        DateReported = dateReported,
                        ManufacturerId = x.Key.ManufacturerId,
                        ManufacturerName = x.Key.ManufacturerName
                    })
                    .ToList();

                var sd2 = sreactivityResults2.ToList();

            }

            return reactivityResults;
```

Comment: I am not sure, are you getting issue when you group by ReactionSimple?

Comment: An enum can be cast to an integer which I think can solve the issue.

Comment: Why do you think it throws of the results? Are the results incorrect or not what you want? Maybe it is returning the correct results but you expect it to something else.

Comment: No errors being thrown, just getting back more results than I should. It happens when I include `ReactionSimple` but the original SQL query which I'm trying to translate into LINQ has `Max(ReactionSimple)` in its selection portion. I've tried changing to a `ReactionSimple = Max(y => y.ReactionSimple)` but that still doesn't work.